# Link the stored procedure to universe

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-server

I am starting the new project. In this project, there will be business objects universe. I want to connect the crystal reports to the universe. So, is it possible to link the stored procedure in crystal reports to the universe as the data source. i.e the stored procedure will use universe structure to generate the data. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not link a Universe to a procedure in CR.  You need to add the procedure to the Universe.

Comment: Do you have any idea of how to deploy the crystal reports on the crystal server. I am using crystal report for visual studio 2010 tool to develop the crystal reports